# Native Base Radio Color Not Working?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I need to set a custom color for Radio button, here is what i tired :

```
<Radio
       color={"#ff0000"}
       selectedColor={"#ff0000"}
       selected={true}
       onPress={ ()=> this.props.somefunc() }
 />
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Share output of this

Comment: **I don't see any color change** for the above code. It show the default lavender color for the radio button. I need to change the radio button to red color.

Comment: You might be doing some mistake, the default Radio button color of NativeBase is blue, not lavendar

Comment: it worked for me after updated the native-base version, there is no color, selectedColor option for Radio Button in <=v2.3.9 Native Base Versions

Answer (score 3):

I find it working. Try this code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Content, ListItem, Text, Radio, Right } from 'native-base';
export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    radioBtnOne: false,
    radioBtnTwo: false
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content>
          <ListItem onPress={() => this.setState({ radioBtnOne: !this.state.radioBtnOne })}>
            <Text>Daily Stand Up</Text>
            <Right>
              <Radio selected={this.state.radioBtnOne} color="red" selectedColor="green" onPress={() => this.setState({ radioBtnOne: !this.state.radioBtnOne })} />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem onPress={() => this.setState({ radioBtnTwo: !this.state.radioBtnTwo })}>
            <Text>Discussion with Client</Text>
            <Right>
              <Radio selected={this.state.radioBtnTwo} color="red" selectedColor="green" onPress={() => this.setState({ radioBtnOne: !this.state.radioBtnOne })} />
            </Right>
          </ListItem>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Gif

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved in the new version of native base (2.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

same problem that's why i used 
library : react-native-flexi-radio-button

also you use one of following libraries 
1: react-native-simple-radio-button
2: radio-button-react-native

Answer (score -1):

When radio button not selected:

```js
 <Radio selected={false} color="gray" selectedColor="green" />
```

When radio button selected: